# printf("string1""string2") is this valid C?

Tags: c, string, standards-compliance

I was trying to figure out something when I wrote this by a mistake

```
printf("string1""string2");
```

To my surprise it compiled and produced a concatenated string output i.e

```
string1string2
```

Is this valid C?

I am using gcc `version 4.4.1 (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is. Consecutive string literals are concatenated early in the parsing of C.

6.4.5 / 4:

> In translation phase 6, the multibyte character sequences specified by any sequence of adjacent character and wide string literal tokens are concatenated into a single multibyte character sequence. If any of the tokens are wide string literal tokens, the resulting multibyte character sequence is treated as a wide string literal; otherwise, it is treated as a character string literal.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and it can be very useful to concatenate string constants at compile-time.

```
#define VERSION "1.0"
#define COMPANY "Trivial Software"

printf("hello world: v. " VERSION " copyright (c) " COMPANY);
```

or

```
puts(
  "blah blah blah\n"
  "blah blah blah\n"
  "blah blah blah\n"
  "blah blah blah\n"
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is valid and has been part of the C language for a very long time (if not since the beginning). The concatenation is done at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

As other said, yes, it is valid. I only wanted to add that it is really useful to input long strings that fill several lines. You don't have to mess with `\` to indicate the string continues, and don't wanting to add a carriage return too, so you just write:

```
"very long string "
"that continues over here"
```

(watch out the spaces at the end of each string, it is a common mistake. In this case, "string" and "that" would be joint.)